# Mixing browserify and webpack externals

Tags: javascript, webpack, browserify

we are in the process of uplifting parts of a huge code base. We are bringing in a module which has been built with webpack. In order to avoid code duplication we have used webpacks externals option.

When we start to integrate our module into the main codebase which is currently using browserify, we have an issue where a shared dependency is included twice and causes issues.

Is there are a way to have webpack use the packaged version of the dependency? So in the final browserified bundle we just have the dependency included once?

It seems to me like this may not be possible, if so I will push for moving the rest of our codebase onto webpack (it is underway already).

The only solution I have come up with so far is to have the webpack module also export the shared dependency, and then have the main app use that export, but this is not ideal.

I have ensured that the dependency in both node_modules folders are at the same version and I still get 2 instances.

I need to be able to tell Browserify to only resolve my apps node_modules, or tell it to resolve from top to bottom, i.e. look in the top level node_modules first, is this possible?

I have tried setting the NODE_PATH option when using the cli to no affect.

** update **

So the issue is that when Browserify hits the require() statement in the webpack bundle it resolves from the local node_modules folder, so we end up with 2 instances of the dependency. I can fix this by using a relative path in either the apps require() or webpacks external option and ensuring they use the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the issue was caused by the fact that I had symlinked (with npm link), the module as I was working on this also. It seems that when Browserify resolves the require in the symlinked module it resolves to its own node_modules, and we end up with 2 copies.

When I install the module normally it all works fine, so this is OK as other consumers of the module should have no issues. It is annoying that it behaves this way, but I just need to ensure that I point at the same dependency in my main app when developing alongside the module.

So my require statement in the main app (while symlinking) looks something like this:

```
require('./node_modules/my-module/node_modules/shared-dependency/index.js');
```

I can require as normal when not symlinking.